# Remote signing of boto request for python client

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I want to directly upload/download files to Amazon S3 from python clients, running in some users machines. I have a server, that hosts the access Id and Secret keys, as they cannot be in the users side, that can be used to generate a pre-signed url, and that the clients can connect via API to request these pre-signed urls.

I have found many examples of JS, but not a single one with python also in the client side (not web based). I have tried to use boto on the client side, but there seems there is no simple way to take advantage of the boto API, but sign the requests with the remote signature.

Is there a way I can use boto to handle the transfers from the client side? So far it seems the best way is to build my own client with python-requests, but I think it pretty much sounds to reinvent the wheel.

So far I have been able to monkey-patch HmacKeys (from boto.auth, in boto2), so the provider.secret_key is no longer required (and doesn't raise NotReadyToAuthenticate()) and I can override the signing, injecting an API call for remote signing. But this seems very tricky, fragile and difficult to maintain. Is there any other way with boto to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than signing URLs (which is typically used when making calls via web browser), you should generate temporary credentials via the [AWS Security Token Service (STS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html).

From your server, issue the [`GetFederationToken` API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetFederationToken.html) to generate temporary credentials:

- The credentials are **time-limited** (up to a maximum of 36 hours)
- Can specify a **policy** that defines the set of permissions being granted
- Then pass these credentials to your client Python app

Your Python app would then use these credentials when calling `boto`. The user will only be allowed to make APIs that you have permitted within your policy, for the time-frame specified.

Comment: Interesting info, but not sure about this, as the access to the files are more file based than credential based. Every download/upload has to be approved by our server permissions policies. I guess I could configure permissions on every resource too, is that the way to go? I will have a look at this approach. Also, the python clients can be several thousands, can this be an issue?

Comment: The [IAM Limits documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-limits.html) don't seem to have any limits to these types of authentication.

Comment: I am exploring this approach, so far so good, I think it might be a better approach than pre-signed URLs, but I still have to figure out a valid permissions approach per-resource and user policies.

Answer (score 2):

I recently published requests-aws-sign, which provides AWS V4 request signing for the Python requests library.

See https://github.com/jmenga/requests-aws-sign

If you look at https://github.com/jmenga/requests-aws-sign/blob/master/requests_aws_sign/requests_aws_sign.py - you will see how you can use Botocore to generate the V4 request signing.

Answer (score 0):

Boto3 gives the ability to create a pre-signed URL for any method call:

From [the Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=presigned#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url):

> `generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod, Params=None, ExpiresIn=3600, HttpMethod=None)`
>
> Generate a presigned url given a client, its method, and arguments
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - ClientMethod (string) -- The client method to presign for
> - Params (dict) -- The parameters normally passed to ClientMethod.
> - ExpiresIn (int) -- The number of seconds the presigned url is valid for. By default it expires in an hour (3600 seconds)
>     HttpMethod (string) -- The http method to use on the generated url. By default, the http method is whatever is used in the method's model.
>
> **Returns:**
>   The presigned url

I just used it to sign a `list_buckets()` call and it returned a big URL, eg:

```
https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAIIIYTGIS5XQCSI6Q&Expires=1441192915&x-amz-security-token=AQoDYXdzENP%2F...37w%3D
```

Pasting it into a browser returned the bucket list in XML.

Comment: I was aware about this pre-signed URLs, what I dont really fully understand is why I cannot use boto in the client side. With that URL I can use python-requests to handle it, but I have to implement file management/streaming, error checks, and some other things that are already implemented in boto.