# Using boto3 with temporary credentials

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I would like to use boto3 to upload a file to AWS S3. But I only have a temporary access to S3, provided by a webservice which is not under my control. I'm provided with the following credential information:

```
    {
        "key": <string>,
        "x-amz-algorithm": <string>,
        "x-amz-credential": <string>,
        "x-amz-date": <string>,
        "policy": <string>,
        "x-amz-signature": <string>
    }
```

As far as I know, these information can be used for a POST request for example. But I was unable to find out how to use this information in combination with the boto3 command

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
```

which needs normally the *aws_access_key_id* and the *aws_secret_access_key*.
This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342519/remote-signing-of-boto-request-for-python-client) suggests, that this should be possible:

> Rather than signing URLs (which is typically used when making calls via web browser), you should generate temporary credentials via the AWS Security Token Service (STS)
>
> [...]
>
> **Your Python app would then use these credentials when calling boto**

But I was not able to find out, how to provide the boto client with the temporary credentials.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that you have been given an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). This is a way of granting temporary access to a specific Amazon S3 command, with a hashed signature that authorizes the request.

While an Access Key and Secret key were used to generate the request, you **cannot extract the Secret Key** from the request. (Rather, it was used to create the signature.) Therefore, you cannot use boto3 to make a request using the supplied information. This is totally intentional.

Generating temporary credentials with the **Security Token Service** is different to generating a pre-signed URL. STS will provide credentials that can be used by boto3. However, that is not what they have done when providing you with access information.

Comment: Thank you for this info. I've thought something like that, but I wanted to know, if it is nevertheless possible to use boto3 with this pre-signed URL.

Comment: No, it is not possible to use it with boto3.